# How to create telerik mvc windows programmatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

There is a command like this that I'm using:

```
var windowElement = $.telerik.window.create({
title: "Insert image",
html: "<strong>Inserting an image...</strong>",
contentUrl: '',
modal: true,
resizable: false,
draggable: true,
scrollable: false,
onClose: function() {}
```

});

But this give me an error saying that $.telerik.window is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the Telerik javascript files to be loaded you will need to include the Telerik ScriptRegistrar at the end of your master page.

Checkout the following article: [Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC Manual](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/getting-started-using-telerik-extensions-for-asp.net-mvc-in-your-project.html)

Looking specifically at the following section:

> The ScriptRegistrar should be placed after all components on the page.
>   Typically you could put the ScriptRegistrar component at the end of
>   the master page.

The ScriptRegistrar searches for the Telerik javascript files in certain locations:

> The ScriptRegistrar component looks for JavaScript files in the
>   following order:
>
> First it will search for a folder with the same name
>   as the version of the Telerik.Web.Mvc.dll assembly located in the
>   Scripts folder of your    ASP.NET MVC application. If such a folder is
>   found the ScriptRegistrar will look for the following extensions:
>
> *.debug.js
>
> *.min.js
>
> *.js
>
> If there is no such folder, the ScriptRegistrar will search in
>   the Scripts folder of the ASP.NET MVC application. It is better to
>   copy the folder with the version for easier upgrade.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Was missing telerik.window.min.js